# How i will get the images of highest scored users?

Tags: users

I am using a Q/A plugin for the user scores, I have function like below, I want to take the images of the highest scored users, how can I get the images of the highest users, and I want to display it in home page with the images and score with separate boxes , like StackOverflow, for running this query do I need `add_filter()`. Where do I add this code?

```
function the_top_qa_users(){
    global $wpdb;

    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = '_qa_rep'
    AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY meta_value DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5");

    foreach($user_ids as $id){
        the_qa_user_link($id);
        echo '<br/>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about what does the function `the_top_qa_users` outputs, I can understand `$user_ids` have the ids of the users. What does `the_qa_user_link($id)` do?

Comment: it will retries highest scored users.

Comment: what do you mean by retries?

Comment: sorry it is Retrieves

Comment: What does the function `the_qa_user_link()` do then, cause I see the variable `$user_ids` gives you the user id order in `DESC`

Comment: and if you have successfully retrieved the user ids use [get_avatar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) to get the avatars/images of the users.

Comment: in this query how can i get the avatar,user id, score, that is my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11924/discussion-between-maruti-mohanty-and-naveen)